# Indexing audio to get timestamps for each word using python

Tags: python-3.x, audio, indexing, speech-recognition

I have an audio file and I want to get the timestamps for each word. I want to know during which time period was each the words spoken.

(For example if an audio file says "I am a doctor" I want to know during which instant "I" was said, "am" was said and so on)

I want to do this using python.
I have tried the following code.

```
from SimpleAudioIndexer import SimpleAudioIndexer as sai
indexer = sai(mode="ibm", src_dir="D:/Codes/Python/audio recognition",      
username_ibm="", password_ibm="")
indexer.index_audio(basename = "target.wav")
indexer.save_indexed_audio("{}/indexed_audio".format(indexer.src_dir))
indexer.load_indexed_audio("{}/indexed_audio.txt".format(indexer.src_dir))
print(indexer.get_timestamps())
```

However I am running into following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Codes\Python\audio recognition\rec.py", line 5, in <module>
indexer.index_audio(basename = "target.wav")
File "C:\Users\Awais\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site- 
packages\SimpleAudioIndexer\__init__.py", line 1108, in index_audio
self._index_audio_ibm(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Awais\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site- 
packages\SimpleAudioIndexer\__init__.py", line 928, in _index_audio_ibm
replace_already_indexed=replace_already_indexed)
File "C:\Users\Awais\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site- 
packages\SimpleAudioIndexer\__init__.py", line 730, in _prepare_audio
self._filtering_step(basename)
File "C:\Users\Awais\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site- 
packages\SimpleAudioIndexer\__init__.py", line 638, in _filtering_step
universal_newlines=True).communicate()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from your code/errors is that you're running Windows, but you're using forward slashes "/" in your src_dir string. This won't work as Windows uses the backslash "\" when navigating folders. Such as:
C:\Windows

while many Unix based systems use the forward slash like this:
/home/Awais

In your code you should try to change the "/" to "\" and see if that makes a difference.

If it is your intention on using this program on both Windows and Unix systems, you should use python3's "pathlib" to ensure your directory paths work on either OS. Here is a link that you can use to learn more about handling paths in python3:

https://medium.com/@ageitgey/python-3-quick-tip-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-file-paths-on-windows-mac-and-linux-11a072b58d5f

Comment: I tried single backslash "\" ,double backslash "\\" and forward slash but none seem to work. Everytime I get the same error.

Comment: Is there any alternative of doing this task.

Comment: Two other thoughts that might help:  1. there is a space in your src_dir's path, see if you can (save your work) and rename the directory you're looking in to "audio_recognition".

Comment: The second thought, is to add a trailing "\" to the end of your src_dir, as the module may be attempting to load "D:\Codes\Python\audio recognitiontarget.wav" instead of "D:\Codes\Python\audio recognition\target.wav"

Comment: You might also add `from pathlib import Path` and then use
`my_file = Path("/path/to/file/target.wav")
if my_file.is_file():  `  and then add your code after that, because if it gets that far the system was able to find your file.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the path. I have tried opening the file using the same path in another program to test if the file or path is incorrect. But the audio plays perfectly fine.

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into my own .py file and ran it testing on a .wav file of my own and my own directories and it worked fine. Where I ran into an issue is when I created a new directory that had a space in it's name and the module rejected it saying it couldn't find the file specified.  I would recommend you remove the space from the directory name and give that a try.

Comment: After looking at the documentation, found this from the author: "Windows is not supported." Here's the link to the github: https://github.com/aalireza/SimpleAudioIndexer/issues/7#issuecomment-473601015

Comment: So is there any other way to index the audio. Basically what I am trying to do is to separate each word into an audio file.  Thanks for your effort 

Comment: You should give the docker install a try as mentioned on the github page for it (it has instructions on how to do all that). Or, you could use virtualbox and install a flavor of linux (ubuntu) and run it from there. Both options are not too difficult to implement. I know it's a bit of a process, but it could work for what you're trying to do.